# Is it possible to stream video from https:// hosted ip address into python with RestAPI , OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, ip-camera

I have hosted a video on an vm ip address using docker.
I need to feed the video into a restapi using its ip address.
How to do it?

Comment: You should be more specific, you mean rest api?

Comment: cap = cv2.VideoCapture('URL')